# Can one find a closed form solution to $\ln x=\frac{1}{x}$,

Tags: closed-form, lambert-w

Is there a closed form solution of the equation $\ln x=\frac{1}{x}$? I couldn't find a proof myself and I don't know any theorems that says when a closed form solution exists.

Comment: Is it useful to point out $W(1)=$ the omega constant?

Answer (score 5):

The (real) solution is $1/W(1)$ where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: Note that by definition $W(1) e^{W(1)} = 1$, so this answer's value is the same as that of @JanEerland's.

Answer (score 5):

The real solution is:

$$\ln(x)=\frac{1}{x}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x\ln(x)=1\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{x\ln(x)}=e^{1}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x^x=e\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$x=e^{\text{W}(1)}$$

With $\text{W}(z)$ is the product log function.

Comment: Letting $x=e^t$ after the second row yields more clarity.